# Class 'Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider' not found

Tags: php, laravel-4, composer-php

I think I got messed up when I try to access my laravel site and got this error:

```
 Symfony \ Component \ Debug \ Exception \ FatalErrorException (E_UNKNOWN)

Class 'Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider' not found
```

I try to do `composer update` but I got this error:

```
 composer update
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

  Problem 1
    - The requested package mews/purifier could not be found in any version, there may be a typo in the package name.

Potential causes:
 - A typo in the package name
 - The package is not available in a stable-enough version according to your minimum-stability setting
   see <https://getcomposer.org/doc/04-schema.md#minimum-stability> for more details.

Read <https://getcomposer.org/doc/articles/troubleshooting.md> for further common problems.
```

I also try the link stated above but nothing happen. this is the content of my composer.json

```
{
        "name": "laravel/laravel",
        "description": "The Laravel Framework.",
        "keywords": ["framework", "laravel"],
        "license": "MIT",
        "require": {
                "laravel/framework": "4.2.*",
                "vtalbot/markdown": "1.*",
                "mews/purifier": "dev-master-14",
                "hybridauth/hybridauth": "dev-master#6d89473",
                "symfony/yaml": "dev-master",
        "greggilbert/recaptcha": "1.*",
                "php": ">=5.3.0",
        "ext-curl": "*",
        "ext-json": "*",
        "gloudemans/shoppingcart": "~1.2",
        "stripe/stripe-php":"dev-master"
        },
        "autoload": {
                "classmap": [
                        "app/commands",
                        "app/controllers",
                        "app/models",
                        "app/database/migrations",
                        "app/database/seeds",
                        "app/tests/TestCase.php"
                ],
                "files" : [
                        "vendor/stripe/stripe-php/lib/Stripe.php"
                ]
        }, "scripts": {
                "post-install-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-update-cmd": [
                        "php artisan clear-compiled",
                        "php artisan optimize"
                ],
                "post-create-project-cmd": [
                        "php artisan key:generate"
                ]
        },
        "config": {
                "preferred-install": "dist"
        },
        "minimum-stability": "dev"
}
```

any ideas?

I got this error because I tried to replace `"mews/purifier": "dev-master-14",` to `"mews/purifier": "dev-master",` but I got error again like in [Composer Update error in Laravel 4 after renaming a controller file](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36355452/composer-update-error-in-laravel-4-after-renaming-a-controller-file) ...

Any idea about my case? any help will be appreciated..

I try also to `composer install` but I get this error:

```
composer install
Loading composer repositories with package information
Installing dependencies (including require-dev) from lock file
Warning: The lock file is not up to date with the latest changes in composer.json. You may be getting outdated dependencies. Run update to update them.
Nothing to install or update
Generating autoload files
> php artisan clear-compiled
PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider' not found in /var/www/staging.theskitrip.ca/protected/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157
{"error":{"type":"Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalErrorException","message":"Class 'Mews\\Purifier\\PurifierServiceProvider' not found","file":"\/var\/www\/staging.theskitrip.ca\/protected\/vendor\/laravel\/framework\/src\/Illuminate\/Foundation\/ProviderRepository.php","line":157}}Script php artisan clear-compiled handling the post-install-cmd event returned with an error


  [RuntimeException]
  Error Output: PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider' not foun
  d in /var/www/staging.theskitrip.ca/protected/vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/
  Foundation/ProviderRepository.php on line 157


install [--prefer-source] [--prefer-dist] [--dry-run] [--dev] [--no-dev] [--no-plugins] [--no-custom-installers] [--no-autoloader] [--no-scripts] [--no-progress] [-v|vv|vvv|--verbose] [-o|--optimize-autoloader] [-a|--classmap-authoritative] [--ignore-platform-reqs] [--] [<packages>]...
```

Comment: can you paste the content of your app.php ??

Answer (score 1):

```
the issue is from your app/config/app.php 

comment this out the service provider 

// 'Mews\Purifier\PurifierServiceProvider',

and then comment out the alias

// 'Purifier' => 'Mews\Purifier\Facades\Purifier',


run composer install && composer update

That should solve the issue.
```